# In XML, check if child nodes contain specific values with C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, traversal

I'm getting back some XML and this is a section of it:

```
<pair name="cf_item7" type="pair">
    <pair name="cf_id" type="integer">34</pair>
    <pair name="value" type="string">0</pair>
</pair>
```

Within the XML are a number of pairs. The section I need to check with always have a name beginning with cf_item* but this could be cf_item7, cf_item6, or any other number.

I need to check within one of these cf_item* sections, and whether or not it has a cf_id, with the content equalling 34 (it will always be 34).

If 34 exists, I need to check the next node (value), and check if it is equal to 0 or 1.

If it equals 0, I need to output a message to the screen (web page).

I've inherited the original code, which is written in C# .net - Can anyone help as it's not a language I'm familiar with?

I started with this, based on some of the other code, but I'm unsure where to go next.

```
if (eleName.Contains("cf_item")) {
     XmlNode nodes = eleList[i].ChildNodes;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the first element with `pair` name then check if the name attribute contains `cf_item`.
If yes, get all elements with `pair` name from that first element.

The result will be in an `IEnumerable<XElement>` then you can check the first element if it contains `34` and if the second element contains `0` or not.

The code will be something like this:

```
XDocument xmldata = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
XElement node = xmldata.Element("pair");
if (node.Attribute("name").Value.Contains("cf_item"))
{
       IEnumerable<XElement> nextElmts = node.Elements("pair");
       if (nextElmts.ElementAt(0).Attribute("name").Value.Contains("cf_id"))
       {
           if ((Convert.ToInt32(nextElmts.ElementAt(0).Value) == 34))
           {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(nextElmts.ElementAt(1).Value) == 0)
                {
                     //do what you want here
                     Console.WriteLine("it's 0");
                }
           }
       }
}
```

Note: this is only for one cf_item. You need to modified it if `cf_item` is more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`, you can do something like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Xml.Linq;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xmlDocument = XElement.Load(@"c:\tmp\foo.xml");

            // Loop over all elements having a "name" attribute starting with "cf_item".
            foreach (var pairElement in xmlDocument.Elements().Where(x => x.Attributes().Any(y => y.Name == "name" && y.Value.StartsWith("cf_item"))))
            {
                // Is there a child element, having a "name" attribute set to "cf_id" with a value of "34"?
                if (pairElement.Elements().Any(x => x.Attributes().Any(y => y.Name == "name" && y.Value == "cf_id") && x.Value == "34"))
                {
                    // Fetch the single element with a "name" attribute set to "value".
                    var valueElement = pairElement.Elements().Single(x => x.Attributes().Any(y => y.Name == "name" && y.Value == "value"));

                    // Output the value of it!
                    Console.WriteLine(valueElement.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No cf_id set to 34.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**XML**

```
<root>
<pair name="cf_item7" type="pair">
    <pair name="cf_id" type="integer">34</pair>
    <pair name="value" type="string">0</pair>
</pair>
<pair name="cf_item8" type="pair">
    <pair name="cf_id" type="integer">34</pair>
    <pair name="value" type="string">1</pair>
</pair>
<pair name="cf_item9" type="pair">    
    <pair name="value" type="string">0</pair>
</pair>
</root>
```

---

**Output**

```
0
1
No cf_id set to 34.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var valueAfter34  = (from e in doc.Descendants("pair")
        where e.Attribute("name").Value.StartsWith("cf_item")
        let itemPairs = e.Descendants()
        from idElement in itemPairs
        where idElement.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("cf_id") &&
              idElement.Value == "34"
        select idElement.ElementsAfterSelf().FirstOrDefault().Value).FirstOrDefault();

if (valueAfter34 == "0")
{
    // show message
}
```

It assumes there is one pair element with cf_id 34. If that's not the case it should need some fiddling.